# booting debugging kernel for perf

Tags: boot, kernel, debug

I am trying to do some performance tests, I found out that most overhead is insde the kernel (kernel.kallsyms).

So I need kernel with debuging symbols and extracted vmlinuz in order to run perf report with -k option..

I installed debugging kernel package from ddebs but I am not sure how to boot the kernel.
I run update-grub2 but the kernel didnt appeared in the list..

I checked the package and found out that the kernel is installed inside /usr/lib/debug - there are its libraries (libc etc) and kernel modules..

Now I am not able to find some way of loading the kernel at boot time.

I guess I need to be runnig kernel with debugging symbols in order perf to work properly with -k option - otherwise the memory addresses wouldnt be mapped properly - right?

I run the perf -k to kernel without running the same one, but I am not sure if this is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Ok actualy its fine running the perf against debug kernel when only normal kernel is loaded.

Btw the kernel was installed with this tutorial for systemtap:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap

I noticed few things - the debug kernel is already extracted - the name is vmlinux not vmlinuz and its big..

the second thing when I load it into gdb I see the exactly same number and the time of build is same as my loaded non-debug kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux delo 3.13.0-55-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:27:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and the gdb (based on [this](http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/setup/ubuntu/):

```
(gdb) print init_uts_ns.name
$1 = {sysname = "Linux", '\000' <repeats 59 times>, nodename = "(none)", '\000' <repeats 58 times>, 
release = "3.13.0-55-generic", '\000' <repeats 47 times>, version = 
"#94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 00:27:10 UTC 2015", '\000' <repeats 21 times>, 
machine = "x86_64", '\000' <repeats 58 times>, domainname = "(none)", '\000' <repeats 58 times>}
```

I mean the part #94... is the same.

When I run the recorded perf with :

```
perf report -g -k /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.13.0-55-generic
```

it actualy works fine - I see the kernel symbols translated to real functions(-g is just for calltrace):

```
- 3,18%  app  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string
 - copy_user_enhanced_fast_string
  - 98,98% system_call 
     -syscall 
       68,60% 0xbeef0100
       31,40% 0xbeee0100 
  + 0,54% generic_file_aio_read
```

someone told me that when the kernel booted and kernel used by perf wouldnt align then I would definitely see it - the functions to kernel samples wouldnt make sense (just some random data instead of real name).